# Function to find string with only one emoji

Tags: javascript

How can I detect that the string only contains one emoji ? Now it returns true if it has any.

I want it only to be true if it contains only one emoji and nothing else.

```
function hasOneEmoji(str) {
    const regEx = /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*/g;

    if (str.match(regEx)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: `const match = str.match(regEx); return match !== null && match.length === 1;`

Comment: But then "Hello" gets true. It can't contain anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the "and nothing else". I assumed you just wanted to avoid matching strings with two or more emojis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your regular expression is correctly matching emojis, then just add `^(?:...)$` around your literal so that's the only pattern allowed in the entire string:

```js
function hasOneEmoji(str) {
  return /^(?:(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?(?:\u200d(?:[^\ud800-\udfff]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff])[\ufe0e\ufe0f]?(?:[\u0300-\u036f\ufe20-\ufe23\u20d0-\u20f0]|\ud83c[\udffb-\udfff])?)*)$/.test(str);
}

console.log(hasOneEmoji(''));
console.log(hasOneEmoji('Hello'));
console.log(hasOneEmoji('Hello'));
console.log(hasOneEmoji(''));
```